# In android layout how do I align elements underneath a listview regardless of the listview's height

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-listview

I've got a listview and I want there to be two textviews and two buttons underneath it (3 of which may be hidden in the code). Every single layout I tried either results in the four elements being anchored to the bottom of the screen even when the listview is only a few lines, or getting pushed off altogether if the listview gets big enough. Any ideas?

Comment: have fixed height for listview or add a footer to listview

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've used `android:layout_below="@id/listVieId"` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` as these would give the results you mentioned. It sounds like what you want is `addFooterView(View v)`

Note what the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) say

> NOTE: Call this before calling setAdapter. This is so ListView can wrap the supplied cursor with one that will also account for header and footer views.

Comment: So If I want to add 4 things to it, I just call addFooterView 4 times? And can I give the views ids that can be referenced in the rest of the program?

Comment: Yes, but note what the docs say, " If addFooterView is called more than once, the views will appear in the order they were added." They can be referenced in this `Activity` or any that has inflated the `layout` that contains them.

Comment: So does that mean I can add button and textviews that were made in the layout?

Comment: So I'm trying to add a textview that I made in Hava using addFooterView and it's treating it like it's part of the listview which I don't want.

Comment: Actually it's always treating the view as a just another thing in the listview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450958/android-how-do-i-get-a-listview-to-stop-treating-a-footer-as-an-element-in-the

Comment: Don't create it in Java. Create a `layout` with the `Views` you will want and use those

Comment: I made a layout in xml told it to add it as a footer and it treats it like another object in the listview