# Android: How do I get a listview to stop treating a footer as an element in the list?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, footer

I'm trying to have some text and some buttons that appears right beneath the listview (which has a custom adapter) in my activity. If the number of things in the list gets too big then it should sit on the bottom of the screen while the list view scrolls on top.

Someone suggested I make a view out of it and put it as a footer but when I do it just treats the footer as a line in the listview and it scrolls with everything else. Here is my code

```
View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.transaction_detail_footer, null);

    TextView t=(TextView)footer.findViewById(R.id.total); 
    t.setText("Total: 558");

    t= (TextView) footer.findViewById(R.id.funds);
    t.setText("Funds: 9800");

    getListView().addFooterView(footer);

    setListAdapter(new TransactionAdapter(TestLV.this,Vs,Vs));
```

Where Vs is a string array.

Does anyone know how to get it to work?

Comment: Why not just put a small linear layout below your listview?

Comment: Because when I try that it pushes that off the screen when the listview gets too big

Comment: Relative layout parent. ListView positioned above the footer LinearLayout

Comment: And what should I put for the ListView's height? I assume we're doing all this in the xml.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal behavior for a `ListView`. `addFooterView()` adds the view to the end of the list, not the bottom of the screen. (See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29)). To achieve what you hope to see, you'll need to place another fixed View below the `ListView` -- for example, a `LinearLayout` containing the `ListView` at the top and another `LinearLayout` at the bottom.

Comment: But what should I put for the height of the listview so that it doesn't crowd out everything else if it gets too big?

Comment: Take a look at the "layout_weight" property. You can set it for all Views inside a LinearLayout.

Comment: Wouldn't just giving just the listview a weight of 1 keep the linearlayout at the bottom even when the listview only has a few lines?

Comment: I would like for the footer to be just beneath the scrolled list if there's only a few lines.

Comment: There was an article by Romaine Guy a couple of years ago, where he indicated that one possibility of a scrolling footer was to set the layout-height to 0dp; however, this was for a `ScrollView` above a footer. I can't seem to google the article, but it's got to be around somewhere. Good luck!

Comment: Here's the article - http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/ -- not sure this helps.